# Hyphenation in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyphenation

I usually use the commands `"-` or `\-` to help LaTeX with the hyphenation of difficult scientific words.

However, this does not work in the bibliography with BibTeX. The titles of my cited publications often contain the names of chemical substances that are hyphenated wrong. Putting `"-` in the titles does not create spots for hyphenation, it just prints the title with the `"-`.

Is there an easy way to solve this problem besides `\hyphenation{...}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a couple of examples of "difficult scientific words" whose hyphenation is supposedly tricky if the words occur in a bib file. Also, what's the issue with providing the relevant hyphenation points in the argument of a `\hyphenation` instruction/

Comment: One reoccurring example would be something like:

\textit{N}-Isopropylamine

It breaks with the hyphen, where it should not break.

Comment: To prevent line-breaking after `\textit{N}-`, you could load the `amsmath` package and write `\textit{N}\nobreakdash-Isopropylamine`. If hyphenation and line-breaking is supposed to be allowed inside `Isopropylamine`, you might write `\textit{N}\nobreakdash-Iso\-propyl\-amine`.

Comment: Thank you! The \nobreakdash- perfectly worked for me.